# Copying Between Workbooks without creating links

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to split data in a worksheet from in a book (BookA) and paste it into several different sheets in another workbook (BookB) using VBA. I want both the vales and format from BookA to be pasted over into the sheets in BookB. However when I do this it creates a link from BookA to BookB. I don't want there to be links between these workbooks.

I've try using the data tab function to break the links, but it doesn't do anything. I've tried copying the sheet from BookA to another book (BookC), and breaking that link, which worked, but when I went to copy data from BookC to BookB it creates a link back to BookA. I've tried putting .BreakLinks after any pasting I do and that doesn't seem to solve the problem either. I've tried using different paste methods to no avail. Has anyone dealt with anything like this before, or have any guesses as to how to break the link between these workbooks or more ideally not have them be generated at all? Any help would be appreciated. If needed I can provide some more detail and a sample of the code.

[Edit] Here's a sample of the code. I didn't include the variable declarations just the part where the books get split, which works, it just makes an unbreakable link

```
    For m = 5 To totalColumnLength Step (1)
       wsb.Activate
       ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
          If (m = LimiterA) Or (m = LimiterB) Then
             If sampleBol = True Then
                rowEnd = m
                LimiterA = LimiterA + 88
                sampleBol = False
             Else
                rowEnd = m
                LimiterB = LimiterB + 88
                sampleBol = True
             End If
             Set pasteRange = wsb.Range(Cell1:="A" & rowStart, Cell2:="aa" & rowEnd)
             wsb.Range(pasteRange.Address).Copy
             If firstSheet = True Then
                newWorkbookb.ActiveSheet.Range("a1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
                newWorkbookb.ActiveSheet.Range("a1").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
                newWorkbookb.ActiveSheet.Range("a1").PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
                firstSheet = False
             Else
                newWorkbookb.Sheets.Add Type:=xlWorksheet
                newWorkbookb.ActiveSheet.Range("a1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
                newWorkbookb.ActiveSheet.Range("a1").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
                newWorkbookb.ActiveSheet.Range("a1").PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
             End If
    rowStart = m + 1  
   End If
Next
```

Comment: Can you share the Code you were trying ? Maybe SO can add something which will make it right for you.

Comment: I've tried doing it a couple of different ways here's the most recent attempt.

Comment: Yes Please edit the question and add your code there.

Comment: Updated with some code

Comment: You are pasting Formats. That's why you are getting link. You want to copy only values  ??

Comment: I would like the format of BookA as well if possible in worksheet or else I'm going to have try to manually set each page in BookB to have that same format which seems like a tedious.